# Path to largest sum

Tags: c#

I'm working with the task of finding the path that gives the maximum sum in a triangle.

The one condition I have is having to switch by even and odd numbers for every row.

So in my example I have to go: 55 - 94 - 95 - 72 ... so I change between odd and even numbers. I found this code that uses dynamic programming to find the path with the largest sum. I also know how to check for even or odd number but I don't know how to use it in this algorithm. Can somebody help with this?

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int[,] list = new int[18,19];
        string input = @"55
                        94 48
                       95 30 96
                     77 72 26 67
                    97 13 76 38 45
                  07 36 79 16 37 68
                 48 07 09 18 70 26 06
               18 72 79 46 59 79 29 90
              20 76 87 11 32 07 07 49 18
            27 83 58 35 72 11 25 57 29 85
           14 64 36 96 27 11 58 56 92 18 55
         02 90 03 60 48 49 41 46 33 36 47 23
        92 50 48 02 36 59 42 79 72 20 82 77 42
      56 78 38 80 39 75 02 71 66 66 01 03 55 72
     44 25 67 84 71 67 11 61 40 57 58 89 40 56 36
   85 32 25 85 57 48 84 35 47 62 17 01 01 99 89 52
  06 71 28 75 94 48 37 10 23 51 06 48 53 18 74 98 15
27 02 92 23 08 71 76 84 15 52 92 63 81 10 44 10 69 93";
        var charArray = input.Split ('\n');

        for (int i=0; i < charArray.Length; i++) {
            var numArr = charArray[i].Trim().Split(' ');

            for (int j = 0; j<numArr.Length; j++)
            {
                int number = Convert.ToInt32 (numArr[j]);
                list [i, j] = number;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 16; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
                list[i,j] = Math.Max(list[i, j] + list[i+1, j], list[i,j] + list[i+1, j+1]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine (string.Format("Maximum total: {0}", list [0, 0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: It look like a school stuff :P

Comment: Do you just need to find the biggest number in each line or really the best path for biggest sum? E.g descending from top, the most left path "55,94,95,77,97,07,48,18,20,27" versus the most right path "55,48,95,67,45,68,06,90,18,85". According to your logic, you should take the left path (94>48), but the right path is actually bigger. I omitted the odd/even requirement just for the sake of an example

Comment: It can be looked as a binary tree with each number having two nodes (left and right). Omitting odd/even requirement you just have to pick the largest number between the left and right node. So you cannot pick 48 because 94 > 48.

Comment: Can you please share expected output sequence and total sum? Also, if I continue the series which you have given as an example 55 - 94 - 95 - 72 ... Next terms will be 97 - 36... OR 97 - 68...

Comment: I wonder if you managed to try my solution, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adopted a different approach for your problem.

First I have defined the triangle structure in which  - excluding  Root and second level, all right hand side children represent also the neighbour left child - excluding the last element on that level.

The traversing of the triangle is pretty simple per se. Once we check for the highest value on that level - we keep track of its parent in order to traverse only trough that path.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Node class
    /// </summary>
    public class Node
    {
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public List<int> Parents { get; set; }
        public int Element { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Triangle class Representation
    /// </summary>
    public class Triangle
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The triangle root
        /// </summary>
        public int Root { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Node per each level of depth
        /// </summary>
        public List<List<Node>> LevelNodes { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Build the triangle structure
        /// </summary>
        public void BuildTriangle()
        {
            List<Node> nodeLevelList = new List<Node>();
            bool carryOn = true;



            //****************************************************
            //Create Root and second level
            Console.WriteLine("Add Tree Root");
            Root = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            LevelNodes = new List<List<Node>>();

            //set the first node to have the root has parent
            Node myNode = new Node
            {
                Parents = new List<int> { Root }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Add Left Child");
            myNode.Element = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            myNode.Level = 2;
            //add the node
            nodeLevelList.Add(myNode);

            myNode = new Node
            {
                Parents = new List<int> { Root }
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Add Right Child");
            myNode.Element = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            myNode.Level = 2;
            //add the node
            nodeLevelList.Add(myNode);
            LevelNodes.Add(nodeLevelList);

            //****************************************************

            Console.Clear();

            //****************************************************
            // Build the rest of the triangle data structure
            while (carryOn)
            {
                nodeLevelList = new List<Node>();
                //take all the nodes on last level entered
                var nodes = LevelNodes.Last().ToList();

                bool firstElement = true;


                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    myNode = new Node();

                    if (firstElement)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Add Left Child for parent : {0}", node.Element);
                        myNode.Element = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        myNode.Parents = new List<int> { node.Element };
                        myNode.Level = node.Level + 1;
                        //add the node
                        nodeLevelList.Add(myNode);

                        firstElement = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var temp = nodeLevelList.Last();
                        temp.Parents.Add(node.Element);
                    }

                    //re-initialise node
                    myNode = new Node();
                    Console.WriteLine("Add Right Child for parent : {0}", node.Element);
                    myNode.Element = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    myNode.Parents = new List<int> { node.Element };
                    myNode.Level = node.Level + 1;
                    //add the node
                    nodeLevelList.Add(myNode);

                }

                LevelNodes.Add(nodeLevelList);
                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to continue adding elements ? Y or N");
                carryOn = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower() == "y";
            }
        }


        public int GetLargetPathSum()
        {
            int result = Root;
            int selectedValue = Root;
            Node nodeSelected = new Node();

            foreach (List<Node> levelNode in LevelNodes)
            {
                int maxValue = 0;

                foreach (Node node in levelNode.Where(x=> x.Parents.Contains(selectedValue)).Select(x=> x).ToList())
                {
                    if (node.Element > maxValue)
                    {
                        maxValue = node.Element;
                        nodeSelected = node;
                    }
                }

                result += maxValue;
                selectedValue = maxValue;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
            triangle.BuildTriangle();

            Console.WriteLine(triangle.GetLargetPathSum());
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, quick and dirty. Took your code and simply added it. There are easier ways to do this!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] list = new int[18, 19];
            string input = @"55
                        94 48
                       95 30 96
                     77 72 26 67
                    97 13 76 38 45
                  07 36 79 16 37 68
                 48 07 09 18 70 26 06
               18 72 79 46 59 79 29 90
              20 76 87 11 32 07 07 49 18
            27 83 58 35 72 11 25 57 29 85
           14 64 36 96 27 11 58 56 92 18 55
         02 90 03 60 48 49 41 46 33 36 47 23
        92 50 48 02 36 59 42 79 72 20 82 77 42
      56 78 38 80 39 75 02 71 66 66 01 03 55 72
     44 25 67 84 71 67 11 61 40 57 58 89 40 56 36
   85 32 25 85 57 48 84 35 47 62 17 01 01 99 89 52
  06 71 28 75 94 48 37 10 23 51 06 48 53 18 74 98 15
27 02 92 23 08 71 76 84 15 52 92 63 81 10 44 10 69 93";

            var charArray = input.Split('\n');

            int[] lineArray = new int[18];
            int highestNumber = 0;

            bool even = false;
            bool noHigehestNumberFound = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
            {
                while (noHigehestNumberFound)
                {
                    //get highest number of a line
                    highestNumber = Convert.ToInt32(charArray[i].Split(' ').Max());
                    if (even != true)
                    {
                        // check odd/even with modulo
                        // if it isn't odd, replace the highest even number with 0
                        if (highestNumber % 2 == 1)
                        {
                            noHigehestNumberFound = false;
                            even = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(charArray[i]);
                            builder.Replace(highestNumber.ToString(), "0");
                            charArray[i] = builder.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (even == true)
                    {
                        // check odd/even with modulo
                        // if it isn't even, replace the highest even number with 0
                        if (highestNumber % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            noHigehestNumberFound = false;
                            even = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(charArray[i]);
                            builder.Replace(highestNumber.ToString(), "0");
                            charArray[i] = builder.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }

                lineArray[i] = highestNumber;
                noHigehestNumberFound = true;
            }

            int count = 0;

            foreach (var item in lineArray)
            {
                count += item;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

With a result of **1383**.

Comment: This code just takes the highest number for each row. You have to consider that each number only has two children. So eg. in line 4: 72 has the children 13 and 76. These are the only two numbers which can be chosen at that line.

Comment: Like a binary tree? You should mention that. The question isn't like that. "Path" is relative. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes like a binary tree

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
var rows = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim());
int sum = int.Parse(rows.First());
bool isFirstOdd = (sum & 1) == 1;
var path = from r in rows.Skip(1)
            let ints = r.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray()
            let isEvenElements = (ints.Length & 1) == 0
            let eligibleElements = ints.Where(x => (x & 1) == (isEvenElements && isFirstOdd ? 0 : 1))
            let b = eligibleElements.Max()
            select b;

sum += path.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

This solution is based on assumption that your series will continue as - 55 - 94 - 95 - 72 - 97 - 68...